# Div is not in same position

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have more than one div in a row. While title is more then one line than div position is changed like below image.
[image]

But I want to keep div image in same position though the title is one line or more than one line. How can I do it?

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can fix by set min-height of outer div of title using css

Comment: Remember when you ask questions on Stackoverflow, you should provide code of your current solution that is minimal, complete and verifiable. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-overflow property of css:

```
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Result will display like "Capetown orphabage.."